# Error : DEP0500

Tags: compiler-errors, windows-10-universal

I have tried compiling several Windows10 UWP programs and I keep getting this error:

```
Error : DEP0500 : The folder "C:\Users\Ikponmwosa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App19\App19\bin\x86\Debug\AppX" could not be deleted.
 Access to the path 'App19.exe' is denied.
```

When I restart VS2015 and run the program the first time it compiles and shows a blank screen. Subsequent compilations results in the error DEP0500 shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio, then delete /bin and /obj directory in project folder and try again

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio, then delete %temp% file directory restart your system and try again